# Arduino, losing value of variable during code execution

Tags: c++, json, debugging, arduino

I'm encountering a strange problem on an arduino sketch.
I'ts a sketch quite complex so i've decided to write in whith classes.
Basically it recieve some data via TCP connection in JSON format and do some operations according form the decoded data.

I decode the received JSON inside the CLASS "PacketManager", using the  library "Arduino Json". Then i pass the JSON object to the class "Bollard" for the execution of the commands (the code will follow). The strange thing is that on the "Bollard" Class in the method "CommandExecutor" I access to the data I passed and I can use them but at some point during the code of the same method that data go to 0. 
Ofcourse i've checked that the the data is not overwriten in the method. The sketch does not have any interrupt or multythread. Seems like the variable get de-allocated form memory or the memory block get overwriten.

/// FRAGMENT OF CLASS PACKETMANAGER THAT RECEIVE THE JSON

```
void PacketManager::readPacket(){
resultRead reads=socket.readSocket();  //get data from soket
if(reads.mainCounter>0){  // if data
  delay(150);
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer; //create a static json buffer form the library ArduinoJson.h
  JsonObject& incomingFrame = jsonBuffer.parseObject((char*)reads.frame); //craete a JSON oblect 
  delay(150);
  incomingFrame.printTo(Serial);  // print the Incoming JSON
  Serial.println();
  if(incomingFrame.success()){ // check if JSON get decoded correclty
    Serial.println("JSON DECODED SUCCESSFULLY");
    unsigned int  eventType=incomingFrame["eventType"];
    unsigned int  packetNumber=incomingFrame["packetNumber"];
    if(eventType==ACK_STANDARD_MESSAGE){ //  ACK standard case
      if(this->checkACK(packetNumber)){  // CHECK If the incoming ACK found a corrispondence with the packet sended
       #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
          Serial.println("ACK RECEIVED");
        #endif
        bollard.commandExecute(incomingFrame);  // if ack is in response of a sended command execute a command form the class bollard.
      }
    }
   ................ CODE CONTINUE. THE ERROR IS ON METHOD bollard.commandExecute(incomingFrame)
```

/////////////// FRAGMENT OF CLASS BOLLARD THAT USE THE JSON OBJECT

```
commandResult* BikeBollard::commandExecute(JsonObject& incomingFrame){
  unsigned int* statusResponse= new unsigned int;  // CREATE STATIC POINTER
  unsigned int* eventType= new unsigned int;
  unsigned int* commandType= new unsigned int;
  unsigned int* packetNumber= new unsigned int;
  // GET DATA FORM THE JSON OBJECT
  unsigned int statusResponse_volatile=(unsigned int)incomingFrame["status"];
  unsigned int eventType_volatile=(unsigned int)incomingFrame["eventType"]; 
  unsigned int commandType_volatile=(unsigned int)incomingFrame["commandType"]; 
  unsigned int packetNumber_volatile=(unsigned int)incomingFrame["packetNumber"];
  // ASSIGN TO THE STATIC POINTED VALUE
  *statusResponse=statusResponse_volatile;
  *eventType=eventType_volatile;
  *commandType=commandType_volatile;
  *packetNumber=packetNumber_volatile;
  commandResult* result;
  Serial.print("STATUS OF THE RESPONSE ");Serial.println(*statusResponse);  // correct value
  Serial.print("EVENT TYPE ");Serial.println(*eventType);  // correct value
  Serial.print("COMMAND TYPE ");Serial.println(*commandType); // correct value
  Serial.print("PACKET NUMBER ");Serial.println(*packetNumber); // correct value

    ///////////////////////////// FROM HERE SOMETIMES THE VALUES *commandType AND *eventType GO TO 0 WITHOUT A REASON /////////////////////////// 

  if(*eventType==ACK_STANDARD_MESSAGE){ //  ACK vase
     Serial.print("STATUS OF THE RESPONSE ");Serial.println(*statusResponse);  // correct value
     *eventType=*commandType;
     Serial.print("STATUS OF THE RESPONSE ");Serial.println(*statusResponse);  // correct value
     result->ackPriority=false;
  } 

  result->type=*eventType;
  #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    Serial.print("BOLLARD: EXECUTE COMMAND "); Serial.println(*eventType);
  #endif
  switch(*eventType){ // wrong value pass form the correct value to 0 sometimes
    case MSG_UP:
    {
      Serial.println("ACK MSG_UP Received");
      result=this->executeMessageUp(*eventType, *packetNumber);  
      break;
    }
    case MSG_LATCH:
    {
      Serial.println("ACK MSG_LATCH Received");
      this->executeMessageLatch(*eventType, *packetNumber); 

      break;
    }
    case MSG_UP_OK:
    {
      // DO SOMETHING
      break;
    }
    case MSG_UP_ERROR:
    {
     // DO SOMETHING
      break;
    }
    case MSG_PRESENT:
    {
     // DO SOMETHING
      break;
    }
    case LOGIN_MESSAGE:
    {
      Serial.println("NOTICE: Logged IN");
      this->loggedIn=true;
      break;
    }  
    case MSG_CARD:
    {
      Serial.println("ACK MSG_CARD Received");
      if(*statusResponse==1){
        Serial.println("DO EXECUTE MSG-UP");
        result=this->executeMessageUp(*eventType, *packetNumber);
      }
      else {
        //DO SOMETHING
      }
      break;
    }
    case MSG_BOLLARD_ACTIVATION:
    {

     Serial.print("STATUS OF THE RESPONSE ");Serial.println(*statusResponse);  // 0  ERROR *statusResponse changed it's value.

     if(*statusResponse==1) {
      if(!this->isActive)checkBollardStatusWaitingTime=CHECK_BOLLARD_STATUS_TIME+1; // set bolard to active
      this->isActive=true;
     }
     else{
      if(this->isActive)checkBollardStatusWaitingTime=CHECK_BOLLARD_STATUS_TIME+1; // check againg the status
      this->isActive=false;
     }
      break;
    }
    default:{
      Serial.print("NOT CODED EVENT "); Serial.println(*eventType);
     result->type=0;
     #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
      Serial.println("Default Message Expired");
    #endif
      break;
    }
  }
  delete statusResponse;
  delete eventType;
  delete commandType;
  delete packetNumber;

  return result;
}
```

Hope someone can help.
Tx for your time.

Comment: You're writing in one line of your code `*eventType=*commandType;`.Do you expect it to be the value pointed to by `commandType` or `eventType` afterwards? Also, why do you assign the value stored in `eventType` to a `commandResult`'s member via an uninitialized pointer? There is no initialization of the object behind between `commandResult* result;` and `result->ackPriority=false;`. If you check for `result->type` instead of `*eventType` in your actual code, then that should cause the issue.

Comment: Tx for your reply, i'm inizializing commandResult* result; on delcaration :
[code](struct commandResult{
  String message="DEFAULT     ";
  String card="";
  bool sendResponse=false;
  int type=0;
  int ackEventType;
  int ackStatus;
  int ackPacketNumber;
  bool ackPriority=false;
 
};)
do you think that is still there the problem?

Comment: And yes i want assign the value of commandType to eventType in the line *eventType=*commandType;

Comment: That are default initializations for objects of type `commandResult`. Your object is of type `commandResult *`, which is supposed to hold an address pointing to where another operation is supposed to have created a struct instance according to your definition. The core question is whether you read the `switch` statement from `eventType` or `result->type`. The latter is stored to random storage which might have been changed by other applications in the meantime. Pointer instance declarations don't initialize the instance pointed to, no matter if there is a default constructor or equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of TinyT i've declared `commandResult* result` as `commandResult result = new commandResult;` and changed the rest of code of consequence and ofc deleting it at the end to prevent a memory leak.
That was the variable that was creating the memory problems.

Tx TinyT